# Creating Cookies in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

Well I have created sessions but having trouble implementing cookies in my website. In config file i have set `$config['sess_expire_on_close']  = TRUE;` so that user's session expires on closing browser. 
Now what i want is, On login if user checks remember me ... all data should be stored in a cookie so that on closing browser, user is still logged on.

```
function login($email, $password, $loginas) {
    if ($loginas == 'user') {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get("user_info");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result() as $rows) {
                $newdata = array('id' => $rows->id,
                    'firstname' => $rows->firstname,
                    'lastname' => $rows->lastname,
                    'address' => $rows->address,
                    'city' => $rows->city,
                    'email' => $rows->email,
                    'phone' => $rows->phone,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            if ($rememberme == 'on') {
                // create a cookie here with all data that i have put in session                                                  
            }
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }    
}
```

Does creating cookie automatically creates session? or we have put these data in session manually again?

Answer (score 3):

In CodeIgniter, you can use [set_cookie()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'The Cookie Name',
    'value'  => 'The Value',
    'expire' => '86500',
    'domain' => '.example.com',
    'path'   => '/',
    'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
    'secure' => TRUE
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Comment: I removed the "." (dot) of the domain name. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to load cookie helper

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

Set your cookie

```
    $cookie = array(
    'name'   => "cookieName",
    'value'  => array('id'=>$rows->id,
    'firstname'=>$rows->firstname,
    'lastname'=>$rows->lastname,
    'address'=>$rows->address,
    'city'=>$rows->city,
    'email'=>$rows->email,
    'phone'=>$rows->phone,
    'logged_in'=>TRUE
        ) ,
'expire' => '86500',
);
```

Just pass your array into set cookie

```
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

And you can retrieve it using

```
$cookie['cookieName']['id'];
```

Also read [manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html)

Comment: how do i check if i have value in cookies at the start of my website ,...
and do i have to put these values in session as well after i closed the browser cuz data in session would be gone by then

Comment: you can check it `if($this->input->cookie('cookiename')!=''){
            //exists
        }`. I think no need to use of cookie here because you already save you data in session!!!

Comment: i need to use cookie because data in session expires if i close the browser. so if user had checked remember me, he would still have to be logged in. 
I dont think above code for setting cookie worked cuz echoing $this->input->cookie('id') didnt show anything